# Hosting both WCF server and client in a same Windows 8.1 machine does not work

Tags: wcf, windows-8.1

I have two web based application. One of them is a WCF server application and the other is a client application and consume first application services.

When they are hosted in a Windows 8 machine's IIS they work good. But when they are hosted in Windows 8.1 they do not work. Client application shows a timeout error message.

Strange point is when client application in Windows 8 connects to server application in Windows 8.1 it works with no problem. If I connect Windows 8.1 client application of Windows 8 server application it works too.

Initially I guessed it may be related to IPv6 so tried to test several IP addresses like localhost, [::1] and many others. But nothing changed.

Now I guess Windows 8.1 has forbidden self WCF hosting (Client and Server in same machine). But have now idea how can I solve problem.

If I use `WCFTesetClient` in Windows 8 machine to test Windows 8 itself or Windows 8.1, both of them works.

I'm using `WSHttpBinding`. Both applications are ASP.NET MVC web applications hosted in IIS.

**UPDATE:**

Why both server and client are on same machine? Because this is a dev machine. In operational environment server and client are on separate machines.

Comment: is that a Windows Store App or A Desktop app in Windows 8.1 ? Have you checked to run the client app as administrator if the client app is a desktop app?

Comment: @KajalSinha please see my update. Both applications are ASP.NET MVC web applications hosted in IIS.

Comment: Mine works in Windows 8.1 ... although it is self hosted, and not IIS hosted. And my app connecting to the self hosted wcf, is a normal windows forms app.

Comment: @afsharm if wcf service can accept remote connections, did you try running the WCFTestClient in elevated mode from the local box(i.e. as Administrator)?

Comment: @KajalSinha Windows 8.1 does not have Visual Studio, so I can not run WcfTestClient from there

Comment: just right click on the WCFTestClient.exe and run as administrator, or if its a console application, run your cmd.exe as administrator and from there launch WCFTestClient.exe

Comment: Windows 8 (or 8.1) really shouldn't be run as a server; both have a maximum number of connections limited to 10. In addition, I have seen WCF reach max connections when calling into the same server on Windows Server editions. That being said, I don't know precisely why yours won't let a single connection go from one to the other.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding any situation where this architecture is beneficial. If you're trying to make an app receive pushed messages then you should use SignalR or some other websockets based tech. And even then there is no reason you can't have all the client side functionality in the same application in which this WCF code is running. Maybe MS is hinting you should fix the fundamental design instead of trying to hack it into oblivion. Addressing technical debt is part of SDL.

Comment: @Matt DeKrey, klatzib, please see my update.